# Show/hide div in viewport after 2 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want  show when its in viewport after 2 seconds. And if its not in viewport just hide.

I watched a code, but its relative to other div and without delay.

Thx!

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($('.waar').is(':in-viewport')) {
        $('.sticky-info').hide();
    } else {
        $('.sticky-info').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: you could use `setTimeout` I guess - though your code seems to hide when it's in viewport and show when it's not

Answer (score 0):

The below SO snippet might help!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      #container {
        height: 1000px;
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 40px;
      }
      #inner {
        width: 50%;
        color: white;
        margin: auto;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: green;
      }

      #sticky-info {
        top: 0;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1;
        display: block;
        background-color: hotpink;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="inner">
        Scroll me out of viewport
      </div>
      <div id="sticky-info">
        Element in view
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      let inView = true;
      let timeout = null;
      window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
        const bounding = document
          .getElementById("inner")
          .getBoundingClientRect();

        if (
          bounding.top >= 0 &&
          bounding.left >= 0 &&
          bounding.right <= window.innerWidth &&
          bounding.bottom <= window.innerHeight
        ) {
          if (!inView) {
            inView = true;
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(() => {
              document.getElementById("sticky-info").style.display = "block";
            }, 2000);
          }
        } else {
          if (inView) {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            inView = false;
            timeout = setTimeout(() => {
              document.getElementById("sticky-info").style.display = "none";
            }, 2000);
          }
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: wow! Thx! This code helped me a lot. To be honest  i want use it to display ads when u are scrolling in a blog. So, you have text, and when u scroll down just banner appear inside the text. Its a good solution? Thx (I removed position: fixed in  #sticky-info. If u have a better solution I would very much appreciate

Comment: You are welcome!! We can only give you suggestions. It's up to you to improvise on top of it..  Please mark as right answer / upvote if the solution helped you. Good day  :)

Comment: To be honest, will be perfect if the show/hide its not realtive to othe class. Just a container and when its in viewport show after 2 secs. (Its not important hide it).

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this link - [slideToggle w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_slidetoggle.asp)

[slideToggle jquery api](https://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)

**Definition and Usage**
The slideToggle() method toggles between slideUp() and slideDown() for the selected elements.

This method checks the selected elements for visibility. slideDown() is run if an element is hidden. slideUp() is run if an element is visible - This creates a toggle effect.

**Syntax**

```
$(selector).slideToggle(speed,easing,callback)

 1. $(Your selectior).slideToggle("fast"); // fast
 2. $(Your selectior).slideToggle("medium"); // meduim 
 3. $(Your selectior).slideToggle("slow"); // slow
```

Another example you can use this also
Please refer this link - > [fadeToggle](https://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/)

```
$(function() {
        $('#ButtonClick').on('click', function() {
            $('#HideShowDiv').delay(1000).fadeToggle();
        });
});
```